# Getting Required data from Url using c#

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have the following url  http://www.toucheradio.com/hostArchivesURLForMobile.php?q=15214&host_id=45.

In this url the data is

```
<table border='0' cellpadding='3' bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="hostinfo_title2"  width='100%' align="center">
            <tr align='center' bgcolor="#ffffff">
              <td width='26%' class="hostinfo_title3">Archive Url</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
              <td height="25" align="center">http://www.toucheradio.com/prgramdetails/20141027_ramesh_ib.mp3</td>

            </tr>
                          </table>
```

And from this i want to get the url  (i.e)http://www.toucheradio.com/prgramdetails/20141027_ramesh_ib.mp3

Can anyone please help me howcan I get this url.I was able to download the url but not knowing how to get mp3 url present in that.

ManyThanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Download the HTML from the URL, use the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack-PCL/) to load the HTML and get the content of the first TD element. Same samples are [here](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples).

Comment: I have used above code but I was getting error in DocumentElement. HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");In search I have changed DocumentElement to DocumentNodes.But in this case I was getting error in SelectNodes.Please help me I was working on this from many dayz..

Comment: I have downloaded the url through webclient.Can you please tell me How can I get the mp3 url from downloaded data.ManyThanks.